# Istio Virtual Service: only allow certain api's to be accessed by a list of Ip addresses

Tags: kubernetes, istio

I have two virtual service config files that get merged into one by istio.

I want a specific API (accounts/v1/invites) to only be accessed by a list of client ip addresses.

This API is will only be called by an external backend server and I want to restrict the ability for the that api to be called by only the IP addresses I list.

My assumption was that listing the ip addresses in the host parameter would enforce this restriction but instead I am not able to access the api at all.

Am I configuring it correctly or am I making a grossly incorrect assumption ?

**--- Virtual Service yaml ---**

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: mp-server-virtualservice
spec:
  hosts:
  - "*"
  gateways:
  - mp-server-gateway              
  http:
  - match:
    - uri:
        exact: /private/api
    - uri:
        exact: /private/graphiql
    - uri:
        exact: /public/api
    route:
    - destination:
        host: mp-server
        port:
          number: 4000
    corsPolicy:
      allowOrigin:
        - 'https://xxxxxxx.com'
      allowMethods:
        - POST
        - GET
        - OPTIONS
      allowHeaders:
        - content-type
        - namespace
        - authorization
      maxAge: 500s
      allowCredentials: true

---
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: mp-server-virtualservice-machine2machine
spec:
  hosts:
  - "138.91.154.99"
  - "54.183.64.135"
  - "54.67.77.38"
  - "54.67.15.170"
  - "54.183.204.205"
  - "54.173.21.107"
  - "54.85.173.28"
  - "35.167.74.121"
  - "35.160.3.103"
  - "35.166.202.113"
  - "52.14.40.253"
  - "52.14.38.78"
  - "52.14.17.114"
  - "52.71.209.77"
  - "34.195.142.251"
  - "52.200.94.42"
  gateways:
  - mp-server-gateway              
  http:
  - match:
    - uri:
        exact: /accounts/v1/invites
    route:
    - destination:
        host: mp-server
        port:
          number: 4000
```

**--- Gateway yaml ---**

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: Gateway
metadata:
  name: mp-server-gateway
spec:
  selector:
    istio: ingressgateway # use istio default controller
  servers:
  - port:
      number: 80
      name: http
      protocol: HTTP
    tls:
      httpsRedirect: true
    hosts:
    - "*"
  - port:
      number: 443
      name: https-443
      protocol: HTTPS
    tls:
      mode: SIMPLE
      serverCertificate: /etc/istio/ingressgateway-certs/tls.crt
      privateKey: /etc/istio/ingressgateway-certs/tls.key
    hosts:
    - "*"
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid that Istio's way of IP based white/black listing access to services inside the mesh is through the usage of listchecker of  IP_ADDRESSES type. Please check the example [here](https://istio.io/docs/tasks/policy-enforcement/denial-and-list/#ip-based-whitelists-or-blacklists).

According to the documentation ([Traffic Management](https://istio.io/docs/concepts/traffic-management/#routing-subset)) the `hosts` under virtual service’s hosts should hold DNS name (not IP address), that needs to resolve to FQDN by cluster DNS server.